# Enhance MVC implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvc

I know that there are several ways to develop the MVC pattern. To improve consistently my knowledge, I would like to get some advice and feedback. How could I enhance my code? I knew that there are several lines of code, but it would be great if you help me improve my skills.

The Model store the object `Person` and notify the view if there are any changes. The view implements the interface `IModelPersonObserver` to receive the notification. The view notify the controller about any changes. The controller starts a new task for long calculations. The result is passed to the model.

To pass different events I am able to use multiple events, like `ModelHandler` and `ViewHandler` based on the real action or just one event and extend the `EventArgs` class.

**IModelPerson**

```
public delegate void ModelHandler<IModelPerson>(IModelPerson sender, ModelEventArgs e);

public class ModelEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Person person;
    public ModelEventArgs(Person p) { person = p; }
}

public interface IModelPersonObserver
{
    void Add(IModelPerson model, ModelEventArgs e);
}

public interface IModelPerson : IModel
{
    void Add(Person person);

    void Remove(Person person);

    void Observe(IModelPersonObserver obsever);
}
```

**ModelPerson**

```
public class ModelPerson : IModelPerson
{
    private readonly ArrayList persons = new ArrayList();

    public event ModelHandler<ModelPerson> change;

    public void Add(Person person)
    {
        this.persons.Add(person);
        this.change.Invoke(this, new ModelEventArgs(person));
    }

    public void Remove(Person person)
    {
        this.persons.Remove(person);
    }

    public void Observe(IModelPersonObserver obsever)
    {
        this.change += obsever.Add;
    }
}
```

**IView**

```
public interface IView
{
    Controller Controller { set; }    
}
```

**IViewPerson**

```
public delegate void ViewHandler<IViewPerson>(IViewPerson sender, ViewEventArgs e);

public class ViewEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public Person person;
    public ViewEventArgs(Person p) { person = p; }
}

public interface IViewPerson : IView
{
    event ViewHandler<IViewPerson> change;
}
```

**ViewPerson**

```
public partial class ViewPerson : Form, IViewPerson, IModelPersonObserver
{
    private Controller controller;

    public event ViewHandler<IViewPerson> change;

    public ViewPerson()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Controller Controller
    {
        set { this.controller = value; }
    }

    private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var person = new Person();
        person.Name = "Name";
        person.Surname = "Surname";

        this.change.Invoke(this, new ViewEventArgs(person));
    }

    public void Add(IModelPerson model, ModelEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("e");
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public abstract class Controller
{
    protected readonly IModel model;

    protected readonly IView view;

    protected Controller(IModel model, IView view)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        this.view.Controller = this;
    }
}
```

**ControllerPerson**

```
public class ControllerPerson : Controller
{
    private static ModelPerson modelPerson;

    public ControllerPerson(ModelPerson model, ViewPerson view) : base(model, view)
    {
        ControllerPerson.modelPerson = model;
        ControllerPerson.modelPerson.Observe(view);

        view.change += ViewOnChange; 
    }

    private static void ViewOnChange(IViewPerson sender, ViewEventArgs viewEventArgs)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Add(viewEventArgs.person));
    }

    private static void Add(Person state)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ControllerPerson.modelPerson.Add(state);
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the naming style. Things like Controller, View etc. should be at the end of the name, not the start. "ViewPerson" sounds like a kind of Person, not a View. "ViewOnChange" is also odd.

Comment: I did that to order the files in the IDE, but you are right. Today I would change the name of those classes.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> public interface IView
> {
>     Controller Controller { set; }    
> }
> ```

## NO!!

You have just coupled the *View* with the *Controller*, which defeats the entire purpose.

This is also broken:

> ```
> public abstract class Controller
> {
>     protected readonly IModel model;
>
>     protected readonly IView view;
>
>     protected Controller(IModel model, IView view)
>     {
> ```

Now you have a *circular dependency*, with the controller knowing about the view, and the view knowing about the controller - but the controller knowing about the view and model is fine:

[image: controller knows about model and view, view knows about model, model knows nothing]

---

I don't understand this line:

> ```
> Thread.Sleep(5000);
> ```

Why sleep for five whole seconds?

---

I'll just add that the naming convention, [as noted by BCdotNET](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66471/enhance-mvc-implementation#comment121186_66471), is off: `ControllerPerson` should be `PersonController` - not because that's how ASP.NET MVC has it, but because C# and the .NET framework in general does it that way; it's just a matter of consistency... and it's what someone maintaining your code would expect to see.

Comment: That was a long time ago. I think I added the `Thread.Sleep` to check if the UI does not block on longer tasks. You are correct with the circular dependency, I already fixed that. Thanks a alot.